# Why the stargazer list length of my github projects are not equal to the star counts?

Tags: github

[image]

https://github.com/drafting-dreams/react-spa-template/stargazers

This is not happening to one project of mine. Nearly all projects, some have more than one stars, and the actual stargazer list length is still one less than the counts.
Any one had the same issue before know what's the issue here?